# Align Alfine 11 when the bolt does not go far enough?

Tags: alignment, alfine

I recently got a new bike (Cube Travel SLT, with belt and Alfine 11).

The hub is not aligned. Looking at the manual, for instance at http://www.koga-signature.com/docs/Maintenance-Manual.pdf (bottom left of page before last) it says to shift down from 11 to 6, then align the yellow dots with the cable adjustment bolt.

Well, the bolt does not go far enough. I can align very precisely when in gear 7, but that's not the point. When I ride, I feel the hub skipping around gear 6-7 and I guess that's the reason.

How can I align the hub when the bolt does not go far enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 'bolt' that the user manual refers to us usually known as a 'barrel adjuster'. Their function is to effectively shorten or lengthen gear or brake cables relative to their housings. In your case this is used to fine tune the cable length to achieve proper gear selection in the hub.

Your problem is that the cable is either too long or short even when the barrel adjuster is at the extremes of adjustment. What's probably happened is that the cable has stretched or the housing has moved a little bit (common in new bikes). The user manual seems to show there is a little clamp on the cable that locks into the hub, the position of that clamp probably needs to be adjusted to bring the gear alignment back into the adjustment range of the barrel adjuster.

If you're not familiar with bike mechanics I'd take it to a bike shop for the adjustment. If the bike is new you should be able to take it back to the shop you bought it from for free adjustments (at least that's common practice I the US, I would assume the same is true in the Netherlands).

Comment: Concur - once the stop is clamped down on the inner cable in the correct place, it won't need to be moved ever again.  The cable life of an alfine inner is much longer than for a brifter-style.  Any stretch/settling should be handled with the barrel adjuster

Comment: Thanks - I followed your advice and took the bike to the shop. What happened is that because of wrong tension only 10 of the 11 gears were used, so the alignment at gear 7 was actually good because it was gear 6. Now skipping is reduced but still exist, so I'll have to go back.

Comment: Guillaume what did you mean there by the "wrong tension"? Do you mean the cable was not lined up correctly using the yellow dots or something else?